# How to get logged in user in a laravel controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel, constructor

What I want to do is to get the a User's activation status before running any methods and redirect if they're not active. Here's my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__CONSTRUCT();
        $this->middleware('auth');
        //SEE IF ACTIVE, something like auth()->user()->active
}

    public function home()
    {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Look at the comment on the last line of the constructor, how do I do that?

Comment: Doesnt this just get explained in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication ?

Comment: @Loko I could get the authenticated user in the methods, it just doesn't work in the constructor, which is where I want it. Check if the authenticated user is active before running any methods. Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 5.3 onwards, you can't directly access session info in a controllers constructor. You can, though, define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor. More info in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if(Auth::user()->active) {
                return Redirect::route('activate');
            }    
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
```